# EF provider specific model configuration (if true then required)

Tags: .net, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.0

How to set to required only if a flag is true?

For example:

```
Property(t => t.DataQualityReview)
.If(t.IsDataQualityReview == true)
.ThenIsRequired()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think a database won't be able to enforce that kind of constraint. 
There are a couple ways you could enforce the requirement a different way.

**Option 1** (preferred):
If you can change the schema of the database, you can create a separate entity/table that will represent `DataQualityReview`.

```cs
public class Foo
{
    // optional DataQualityReview
    public int? DataQualityReviewId { get; set; }
    public DataQualityReview DataQualityReview { get; set; }
}
public class DataQualityReview
{
    public int DataQualityReviewId { get; set; }

    // required properties of a review
    public string Comments { get; set; }
    public int Rating { get; set; }
}
```

The idea here is that `Foo` may or may not have a `DataQualityReview`. If it does have a review, then you could enforce other properties (e.g. `Comments`, `Rating`, etc) that should be required.

**Option 2**: If you cannot change the database. You could enforce this on the class itself.

```cs
public class Foo
{
    // notice `private set`
    public bool IsDataQualityReview { get; private set; }
    public string DataQualityReview { get; private set; }

    public void UpdateReview(string review)
    {
      DataQualityReview = review;
      IsDataQualityReview = review != null;
    }
}
```

As shown, you cannot change the `IsDataQualityReview` and `DataQualityReview` outside `Foo`. Then you expose a method `UpdateReview` that changes both those properties based on the review.